# How to turn a MacBook into a peripheral with services for BLE scanning?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to use my MacBook as a peripheral with services for bluetooth scanning so it can be used like this:

```
 var manager:CBCentralManager? 

  manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)//the withServices will be replaced with custom service UUID
```

I tried creating my own custom service UUID and adding it to the peripheralManager like so:

```
var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createServiceUUID()
         peripheralManager?.startAdvertising(["Test" : "Test"])
    }


    func createServiceUUID() {
        let customServiceUUID = CBUUID(string: customServiceUUIDString)
        let mutableService = CBMutableService(type: customServiceUUID, primary: true)
        peripheralManager?.add(mutableService)
    }
```

I then tried scanning for the serviceUUID I just created but it doesn't show up:

```
 manager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string: customServiceUUIDString)], options: nil)
```

I feel like I may be missing a step to turn my Mac into a Peripheral that can be discovered using the

> scanForPeripherals(withServices:)

function. Any thoughts on how to make this happen?